# how to get Iteration Id for items in array using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a simple ADF pipeline which contains 1 lookup (which loads the name of tables to be migrated) and a ForEach activity (Which contains copy activity and a function App to loads data in BQ). I want to get the Iteration ID and want to send it to Azure function App.
Let say the  Lookup returns a JSON with three tables in it (A,B,C) I want to get the iteration id inside the foreach loop for example 1 for A and 2 for B and 3 for C.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi there Syed, could you please post the code you have tried before to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lookup table from which I was going to pick the Source and destination tables/databases. I added another column with the Iterator number like 1, 2,3,4 for each row in the Source table from which the lookup activities is retrieving the data.

Then inside Azure data factory, I read that column inside the Foreach loop. For each of the Source and Destination tables I have a self made Iterator and used that for my purpose. It worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @paddy you can see the custom solution here

Comment: All right...you added another column...yeah,as you said,my solution will generate additional consumption, but it won't change source data. You could mark yourself to end this case. Thanks for you sharing anyway~

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is a common requirement,but it seems no direct way to get the array index inside the `for-each` activity. However,you could try my little trick with `AzureFunction` Activity.

***Step1:*** Create a text file (named as `index.txt`)in the some blob storage path and store `1` value in it(for using it as array index)

***Step2:*** Inside the For-each Activity, use LookUp Activity to read the value of `index.txt`. First time, it is `1`.

[image]

***Step3:*** After that, execute an Azure Function Activity to change the value --plus 1.So that,next time it is `2`.

***Step4:*** When you finish For-each Activity,you could reset the value as `0` by Azure Function Activity.

No need to create 2 azure functions,just 1. You could pass a `boolean` parameter to distinct whether this invoke is for reset or plus.

Comment: Hi Jay,
This seems to be a nice solution but was a long one and a function App is required to do the calculation.